# Can I use rollBack() before commit()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

Here is my script:

```
try{
    $db_conn->beginTransaction();

    $stm1 = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET col = 'updated' WHERE id = ?");
    $stm1->execute(array($value));
    $done = $stm->rowCount();

    if ($done){
        try {
            $stm2 = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT into table2 (col) VALUES (?)");
            $stm2->execute(array($id));

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            if ((int) $e->getCode() === 23000) {  // row is duplicate
                $stm3 = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM table2 WHERE col = ?");
                $stm3->execute(array($id));

            } else {
                $db_conn->rollBack();    -- this
            }
        }

    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    $db_conn->commit(); 
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $db_conn->rollBack();
}
```

As you see there is a `rollBack()` before `commit()` *(where I've commented by `-- this`)*. Well is what I'm doing correct? Or that `rollBack()` is useless?

**Note:** that `DELETE` statement acts as an undo. Suppose you give a vote to a post and you want to take it back. So that `DELETE` statement remove it if you send a vote twice.

Comment: The whole point of the rollback is so that you don't need to manually reverse inserts with a delete (a rollback does that for you, that's what "rollback" means).... and you don't need to nest the try/catches either; just use the outer one

Comment: @MarkBaker *"just use the outer one"*, what are you talking about? `try/catch` or `rollBack()` ?

Comment: I mean just use one try/catch block that rolls back on Exception... get rid of that try/catch block inside the `if ($done){`

Comment: @MarkBaker Well I can't ..! I have to use a nested try/catch to determine duplicate ..! Actually I'm trying to do this: Update *table1* then insert/delete from *table2* .. Inserting or deleting is based on being duplicate.

Comment: Yes, you can. You are already catching the same exceptions with the outer try.

Comment: @rjdown Well finally is that nested `rollback()` necessary or not?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to make it quite so complicated.

You can run the 2 queries within a single `try/catch` as any of the queries that has an isse will throw an exception, and then you can do a single rollback.

If the first query fails, the database will not be changed, the rollback will just close the transaction. If the second query fails the rollback will UNDO the first query i.e. the UPDATE you did previously.

If both queries complete OK, the commit will apply the changes to the database.

```
try{
    $db_conn->beginTransaction();

    $stm1 = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET col = 'updated' WHERE id = ?");
    $stm1->execute(array($value));

    $stm2 = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT into table2 (col) VALUES (?)");
    $stm2->execute(array($id));

    $db_conn->commit(); 
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $db_conn->rollBack();
}
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

I see what you think you were trying to do. BUT!

If the INSERT fails with a `23000` error code, then the INSERT will not have been done. Your unnecessary attempt to delete the failed INSERT will actually DELETE the row that was there originally i.e. the original vote that should not be deleted!

Comment: Your code isn't the same as mine ..! Where is `DELETE` statement?

Comment: You dont need to DELETE as the ROLLBACK will UNDO both the UPDATE and the INSERT when it is run

Comment: The delete statement is completely unnecessary, that's why it isn't there.... exactly as I said in my first comment to your question

Comment: @MarkBaker Then I'm pretty sure you don't know what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Deleting on duplicate is a part of plan ..! I mean I want to do even deleting on successful execution ..! My purpose of writing that `DELETE` statement isn't for when execution fails .. I'm trying to delete a row if it is duplicate ... it is nothing to do with rollback at all.

Comment: See additional notes. I think that shoudl explain why the DELETE after failed INSERT was also unnecessary and in fact dangerous

Comment: You know .. that's exactly what I want to do: *"the original vote  **should** be deleted"* ...! *(by the way that voting-system is just an example)*

Comment: But you were quite happy with the original row being there BEFORE you attempted to duplicate it. Why would you delete it just because you tried to INSERT it a second time. The second INSERT will not actually CREATE A DUPLICATE it will fail with error code `23000`

Comment: I want to update *table1*, when update is done then I want to insert a row into *table2*, and if that row is duplicate, I want to remove it. That's the plan. Also I want to make sure either all those statements execute, or none of them .. That's why I've used transaction. Now may you please edit my code? or tell me it is fine?

Comment: So you specifically want to remove the row that was on the table before you attempted to duplicate it so not only will the duplicate not be there but also the original row that was placed for some other reason will also be removed.

Comment: Look, I wan't to remove every row which is duplicate .. both new one *(which is failed)* and original one.

Comment: Ok pal that attitude is not helping

Comment: Why? I did it already and all fine .. Now my question is, how can I use transactions for multiple statements and try/catch?

Comment: This is sounding like a `LIKE/UNLINK` senario. In which case the process should be specific to what you are doing. What you have tried seeems very _un-intuitive_ and will look odd to any coder that see's it, and **raise red flags**. Maybe you should consider changing the link that causes this processing to happen, so it specifically removes this row rather than doing it as an aftershock to some other process i.e. change the link from VOTE to UNVOTE and write code specific to that process

Comment: Fine .. I can do that the other way .. I can write a `SELECT` statement to detect row exists or not, and insert/delete that row based on that. Would be that correct?

Comment: YES that would be a much better solution. That way the code is self documenting

Comment: Alright ... Just tell me if I update a row and immediately select it, the result of select statement will be updated-value or old-value? *(pay attention both of them are warped into transaction)*

Comment: But you are updating `table1` and then checking _with a select_ from `table2` So i dont think the question is relevant

Comment: Actually that's a good point you said .. But trust me, I know what I'm doing `:-)` ..! Just suppose I want to both update and select `table1` .. So?

Comment: You are in a transaction, so you should see the data you have updated and not the row before your update. Others will see the database in a state BEFORE your update, or be locked out until you commit or rollback

Comment: I see. +1 for your explanations ..!

Comment: Just to be sure, current value is `x`. I want to update it and set it `y`. and now I want to select it. Is that `x` or `y` ? *(I'm on transaction)*

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work fine. You can get rid of your inner rollback if you would rethrow your error (that would be the "standard way"):

```
try {      
    ...
    if ($done){
        try {
            ...
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            if ((int) $e->getCode() === 23000) {  // row is duplicate
                ...
            } else {
                throw $e;                    
            }
        }
        ...
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }
    $db_conn->commit(); 
}
catch(PDOException $e){
   $db_conn->rollBack();
}
```

In this case, your final `rollback` will handle all exceptions that should be rolled back, while handling the one exception `23000` yourself without rollback.

And it would work fine in your code too. Technically, you can in fact combine as many `commits` and `rollbacks` as you want without resulting in an error - if you `commit` after a `rollback`, it will just commit nothing, because it rolled back already. If you use `rollback` without `start transaction` (in autocommit mode), it will just do nothing. It is just a little harder to maintain the code and to see the strcuture, that's why you usually would use the "standard way" above.

There is just one important thing to consider: transactions in mysql are not nested. If you use `start transaction`, it will automatically do a `commit` before that. So e.g.

```
 start transaction;
 delete from very_important_table;
 start transaction;  -- will do an autocommit
 rollback;
 rollback;           -- will have no effect;
 commit;             -- will have no effect;
 rollback;           -- will have no effect;
```

will not rollback your `very_import_table`, because the 2nd `start transaction` already committed it.

Comment: Also your second `else` should be replace with `catch`

Comment: @stack that else belongs to your `if ($done){`, I forgot the `if` in my code, I will add it.